# Dividir uma frase em 2

Tags: php

Em PHP recebo uma frase do banco de dados, exemplo: `Nome do produto teste cadastrado no banco`

Preciso separar ela em duas, assim:

```
Nome do produto teste
cadastrado no banco
```

Ou seja, o mais na metade possível, como fazer isso? Tentei contando os caracteres e dividindo na metade, mas acaba cortando uma palavra no meio, assim:

```
$nomeProd = "Nome do produto teste cadastrado no banco";
$nomeCaracter = (strlen($nomeProd))/2;
$nome1 = substr($nomeProd, 0, $nomeCaracter);
$nome2 = substr($nomeProd, $nomeCaracter);
echo $nome1;
echo "<br>";
echo $nome2;
```

O resultado foi esse:

```
Nome do produto test
e cadastrado no banco
```

Reparem que a palavra `teste` se separa, e não poderia ocorrer isso.

Comment: uma solução seria contar os espaços e dividir a frase no espaço do meio

Comment: Mas acaba cortando uma palavra na metade....

Comment: de uma olhada na função `substr()` :http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php

Comment: Dei uma explicada melhor na dificuldade @ThiagoDrulla

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma solução bem básica:

```
<?php    
    $frase = 'Nome do produto teste cadastrado';
    $partes = explode(' ', $frase);
    $quant = count($partes);
    $div = ceil($quant / 2);
    $items = array_chunk($partes, $div);

    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        echo implode(' ', $item);
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Pega a frase e extrai em partes pelo fator espaço em branco, a quantidade de itens desse `array` divide por 2 e se houver valor quebrado arredonde pra cima, após isso utilize arra_chunk para a divisão do `array` em duas partes e depois é só imprimir os valores com `implode`.

Acredito que isso pode te ajudar a colocar em seu código fazendo uma adaptação e nesse [exemplo online pode constatar a geração da informação](https://ideone.com/I1pe6J).

---

Pode ser criado uma função e dividir essa frase como quiser:

```
<?php

    $frase = 'Nome do produto teste cadastrado';
    $count_itens = 2;

    function dividir_texto($texto, $count_itens)
    {
        $array_retorno = array();
        if (!empty($texto))
        {
            $partes = explode(' ', $texto); 
            $div = ceil((count($partes)) / $count_itens);
            $items = array_chunk($partes, $div);
            foreach($items as $item)
            {
                $array_retorno[] = implode(' ', $item);
            }
        }
        return $array_retorno;
    }

    print_r(dividir_texto($frase, $count_itens));
```

tendo o seguinte saída de resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Nome do produto
    [1] => teste cadastrado
)
```

[e confira o exemplo online](https://ideone.com/YJQzzH)

Answer (score 4):

Cara, deve ter forma mais simples. Mas assim acho que funciona.
Não testei pois não tem como agora.

```
$frase = "Nome do produto teste cadastrado";

function divide($frase) {

    $quebra = explode(" ", $frase);
    $meio = count($quebra)/2;
    $parte = "";

    foreach($quebra as $k => $v) {

        if ($k <= $meio) {

            $parte[0] .= $v . " ";

        } else {

            $parte[1] .= $v . " ";  
        }

    }

    return $parte;
}


$p = divide($frase);

echo $p[0] . "<br>" . $p[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Creio que esta solução também seja válida

```
<?php

//Frase para dividir ao meio
$nomeProd = "Nome do produto teste cadastrado no banco";

//Quantidade de letras da frase
$comprimento = strlen($nomeProd);

//Obtem a metade da frase, e subtrai 1 para saber o indice da string (pois começa em 0)
$metade = (int) ceil($comprimento / 2) - 1;

//Caminha ate a metade ser um espaco em branco, assim nao quebra a palavra
$letra = $nomeProd[$metade];
while ($letra !== ' ') {
    $metade++;
    $letra = $nomeProd[$metade];
}

//Divide a string pela metade
$str1 = substr($nomeProd, 0, $metade);
$str2 = substr($nomeProd, ($metade + 1), $comprimento);

echo $str1 . PHP_EOL;
echo $str2 . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar também `array_slice()` (fatiar a array). O princípio é o mesmo: quebrar o texto em array, em seguida contar o tamanho da array e dividir por 2. Se o resultado for ímpar, a primeira parte será a metade do número de palavras +1 e a segunda parte o restante. Se for par, obviamente cada parte ficará com a metade de palavras.

```
$texto = "Nome do produto teste cadastrado no banco";

function divStr($string){
   $array = explode(" ", trim($string));
   $array_len = sizeof($array);
   $limite = $array_len%2 == 0 ? $array_len/2 : floor($array_len/2)+1;

   $texto1 = implode(" ", array_slice($array, 0, $limite));
   $texto2 = implode(" ", array_slice($array, $limite));

   return [$texto1, $texto2];
}

var_dump(divStr($texto));
```

Retorno:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(21) "Nome do produto teste"
  [1]=> string(19) "cadastrado no banco"
}
```

**[Teste no Ideone](https://ideone.com/DnUiDA)**